# Django: Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '(49,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tidbit/delete_tidbit/']

Tags: python, django, backend

Can't figure out how to solve this error

Here is the urls.py snippet:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^delete_tidbit/', views.delete_tidbit, name='delete'),
    ...
]
```

The view:

```
def delete_tidbit(request, pk):
    tidbit = Tidbit.objects.get(pk=pk)
    tidbit.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

And the portion of the template that raises this error:

```
<a href="{% url 'delete' tidbit.pk %}">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
url(r'^delete_tidbit/', views.delete_tidbit, name='delete'),
```

This URL doesn't accept an argument, where as you are trying to give it one.

Try this instead:

```
url(r'^delete_tidbit/(?P<pk>.*)', views.delete_tidbit, name='delete'),
```

---

**But beware**: you are accepting GET requests to delete items in your database, any crawler coming across those links may try to follow them and inadvertently delete your data. Consider using a GET that delivers a form to be POSTed to ensure an actual user is doing the action.

Comment: Perfect. And thank you, I will surely look into that.